# Will I develop good/bad habits because of lazy evaluation?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm looking to learn functional programming with either Haskell or F#.

Are there any programming habits (good or bad) that could form as a result Haskell's lazy evaluation? I like the idea of Haskell's functional programming purity for the purposes of understanding functional programming. I'm just a bit worried about two things:

1. I may misinterpret lazy-evaluation-based features as being part of the "functional paradigm".
2. I may develop thought patterns that work in a lazy world but not in a normal order/eager evaluation world.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are habits that you get into when programming in a lazy language that don't work in a strict language.  Some of these seem so natural to Haskell programmers that they don't think of them as lazy evaluation.  A couple of examples off the top of my head:

```
f x y = if x > y then .. a .. b .. else c
  where
    a = expensive
    b = expensive 
    c = expensive
```

here we define a bunch of subexpressions in a `where` clause, with complete disregard for which of them will ever be evaluated.  It doesn't matter: the compiler will ensure that no unnecessary work is performed at runtime.  Non-strict semantics means that the compiler is able to do this.  Whenever I write in a strict language I trip over this a lot.

Another example that springs to mind is "numbering things":

```
pairs = zip xs [1..]
```

here we just want to associate each element in a list with its index, and zipping with the infinite list `[1..]` is the natural way to do it in Haskell.  How do you write this without an infinite list?  Well, the fold isn't too readable

```
pairs = foldr (\x xs -> \n -> (x,n) : xs (n+1)) (const []) xs 1
```

or you could write it with explicit recursion (too verbose, doesn't fuse).  There are several other ways to write it, none of which are as simple and clear as the `zip`.

I'm sure there are many more.  Laziness is surprisingly useful, when you get used to it.

Comment: I like the last sentence of your answer :)

Answer (score 11):

You'll certainly learn about evaluation strategies. Non-strict evaluation strategies can be very powerful for particular kinds of programming problems, and once you're exposed to them, you may be frustrated that you can't use them in some language setting.

> I may develop thought patterns that work in a lazy world but not in a normal order/eager evaluation world.

Right. You'll be a more rounded programmer. Abstractions that provide "delaying" mechanisms are fairly common now, so you'd be a worse programmer not to know them.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. I may misinterpret lazy-evaluation-based features as being part of the "functional paradigm".

Lazy evaluation *is* an important part of the functional paradigm.  It's not a requirement - you can program functionally with eager evaluation - but it's a tool that naturally fits functional programming.

You see people explicitly implement/invoke it (notably in the form of lazy sequences) in languages that don't make it the default; and while mixing it with imperative code requires caution, pure functional code allows safe use of laziness.  And since laziness makes many constructs cleaner and more natural, it's a great fit!

(Disclaimer: no Haskell or F# experience)

Comment: Examples of explicit implementations: LINQ, the centerpiece of C# 3.0, makes heavy use of lazy sequences and took direct inspiration from Haskell. Lazy sequence building with a coroutine-style syntax (commonly some variant on a `yield` keyword) appears in multiple languages. OO languages with "properties" allow the technique of delaying expensive computations until the getter is called, then caching the value. In Haskell, you get all of that automatically as part of the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Beni's answer: if we ignore operational aspects in terms of efficiency (and stick with a purely functional world for the moment), every terminating expression under eager evaluation is also terminating under non-strict evaluation, and the values of both (their denotations) coincide.

This is to say that lazy evaluation is strictly more expressive than eager evaluation. By allowing you to write more correct and useful expressions, it expands your "vocabulary" and ability to think functionally.

Here's one example of why: 
A language can be lazy-by-default but with optional eagerness, or eager by default with optional laziness, but in fact its been shown (c.f. Okasaki for example) that there are certain purely functional data structures which can only achieve certain orders of performance if implemented in a language that provides laziness either optionally or by default.

Now when you do want to worry about efficiency, then the difference does matter, and sometimes you will want to be strict and sometimes you won't.

But worrying about strictness is a good thing, because very often the cleanest thing to do (and not only in a lazy-by-default language) is to use a thoughtful mix of lazy and eager evaluation, and thinking along these lines will be a good thing no matter which language you wind up using in the future.

Edit: Inspired by Simon's post, one additional point: many problems are most naturally thought about as traversals of infinite structures rather than basically recursive or iterative. (Although such traversals themselves will generally involve some sort of recursive call.) Even for finite structures, very often you only want to explore a small portion of a potentially large tree. Generally speaking, non-strict evaluation allows you to stop mixing up the operational issue of what the processor actually bothers to figure out with the semantic issue of the most natural way to represent the actual structure you're using.

Comment: Methodologically disagree for various reasons: (1) Certain properties of efficiency (like proper tail recursion) does couple with how we program deeply, so efficiency in general should be worth worrying at the very first time. (2) Lazy evaluation is NOT necessarily strictly more expressive than eager evaluation. (Consider the untyped lambda calculus.) Besides, the expressiveness here seems quite underspecified, comparing to [some serious treatments](https://ftp.cs.wpi.edu/pub/techreports/pdf/08-01.pdf).

Comment: (3) Features like type systems play a big role on usefulness. Lazy-or-not counts, but the differences in practice are not that big. (4) Flavor on infinite structures implies certain philosophy ideas like Platonism, which is not the truth that everyone will accept. The timing to introduce the infinity property is not that obvious in general cases.

Comment: (5) Any models implementable by programs running on physical computers are resource-bound. Respecting this is not minor operational issue, but mostly vital, esp. when the program runs in a hosted implementation backed by a time-sharing OS so users can't totally ignore the effect of the resource consumption on other programs. Building appropriate abstraction to hide uninterested underlying implementation details is certainly good, but cleanup _all_ of the "mixture" is a non-starter when the computer has limited memory. Once this is true, "infinite" is not for free like it in the ideal world.

Comment: I gave a formal sense to expressiveness in citing the work by Okasaki -- in a pure setting, lazy langauges can express strictly more algorithms.

Comment: I am not totally against those settings of view, but the normal "expressiveness" (based on equivalence among rewriting) are quite weak properties for many practical uses. For example, it usually cannot properly model the computational complexity (proper tail recursion is once again an example), albeit this can be expressed in some meta language. And in certain case, _less_ expressiveness is needed (notably, you don't want typechecking Turing-complete so a typechecker may run forever).

Comment: Moreover, the guarantees are always voided where users can specify the evaluation rules in the language. For a system allowing this by the user program, lazy-by-default rules can be simulated with implementations of the intended lazy data structures side-by-side with an opted-in (so no need "by default") user-provided evaluator. Such system are "non-strict" in some sense, but not necessarily "lazy". (Well, this is a quite weak conclusion because ordinary strict languages also have non-strict parts...) Formally, I suggest to take a look at the abstractive power (link above) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, i found myself doing Haskell-style programming in Python. I took over a monolithic function that extracted/computed/generated values and put them in a file sink, in one step.

I thought this was bad for understanding, reuse and testing. My plan was to separate value generation and value processing. In Haskell i would have generated a (lazy) list of those computed values in a pure function and would have done the post-processing in another (side-effect bearing) function.

Knowing that non-lazy lists in Python can be expensive, if they tend to get big, i thought about the next close Python solution. To me that was to use a generator for the value generation step.

The Python code got much better thanks to my lazy (pun intended) mindset.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect bad habits.

I saw one of my coworkers try to use (hand-coded) lazy evaluation in our .NET project. Unfortunately the consequence of lazy evaluation hid the bug where it would try remote invocations before the start of main executed, and thus outside the try/catch to handle the "Hey I can't connect to the internet" case.

Basically, the manner of something was hiding the fact that something really expensive was hiding behind a property read and so made it look like a good idea to do inside the type initializer.

Comment: I think this is a bad example. Non-strict evaluation makes the most sense in a purely functional setting, either by definition with the absence of side effects (e.g. Haskell) or by construction with that absence (i.e. by the discipline of the programmer to not place effectful actions behind thunks). Lazy initialization in languages with mutation is a tricky business and perhaps often wrong, but that's very distinct from anything resembling lazy evaluation in a purely functional setting.

Comment: @sclv: Speaking of bad examples, what about lazy IO in Haskell? Good old `unsafeInterleaveIO`...

Comment: There is a saying "Lisp users know the value of everything and the cost of nothing."

Comment: Equivalently, you could say that C programmers learn bad habits because they leave dangling pointers.  Just because your coworker used laziness incorrectly doesn't mean laziness teaches bad habits, and lazy I/O is often considered problematic in Haskell.

Comment: that saying, which is a [perlisism](http://www.cs.yale.edu/quotes.html) has nothing to do with lazy evaluation. It refers to the fact that in lisp all expressions are values (which is true of any functional language) in conjunction with the memory overheads associated with lisp at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Contextual information missing.

Laziness (or more specifically, the assumption of the availabilty of the purity and equational reasoning) is sometimes quite useful for specific problem domains, but not necessarily better in general. If you're talking about general-purpose language settings, relying on the lazy evaluation rules *by default* is considered harmful.

## Analysis

Any languages has functional combination (or the applicable terms combination; i.e. function call expression, function-like macro invocation, FEXPRs, etc.) enforces rules on evaluation, implying the order of different parts of subcomputation therein. For convenience and the simplicity of the specification of the language, a language usually specify the rules in a flavor paired to the [reduction strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_strategy):

- The strict evaluation, or the applicative-order reduction, which evaluates all subexpression first, before the subcomputation of the remaining evaluation of the hole combination.
- The non-strict evaluation, or the normal-order reduction, which does not necessarily evaluate every subexpression at first.

The remaining subcomputation finally determines the result of the whole evaluation of the expression. (For program-defined constructs, this usually implies the substitution of the evaluated argument into something like a function body, and the subsequent evaluation of the result.)

[Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), or the call-by-need strategy, is a typical concrete instance of the non-strict evaluation kind. To make it practically usable, subexpression evaluations are required to be pure (side-effect-free), so the reductions implementing the strategy can have the [Church-Rosser property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem) whatever the order of subexpression evaluation is actually adopted.

One significant merit of such design is [the availability of the equational resoning](https://jgbm.github.io/eecs762f19/papers/wadler-monads.pdf): users can encode the equality of expression evaluation in the program, and optimizing implementation of the language can perform the transformation depending directly on such constructs.

However, there are many serious problems behind such design.

- Equational reasoning is not important as it in the first glance in practice.

  - The encoding is not a separate feature. It has some specific requirements on the other features to carry the encoding. For a pure language, it is even more difficult to encode them elsewhere, so there is certain pressure to make the type system more expressive, hence more complicated typing and typechecking.
  - Whether the compiler uses the equational reasoning directly encoded in the program or not is an implementation detail. It is more of a taste of style to promote the importance.
  - Syntatic equations are not powerful enough to encode semantic conditions like cases of "unspecified behavior" in ISO C. It still needs some additional primitives to express non-determinism of such semantic equivalence classes to make optimization techniques based on such equivalence possible.
- It is computationally inefficient at the very basic level by default, and not amendable by the programmer easily.

  - There is no systemic way to reduce the cost on equations which are known not required by the programmer.
  - One of the significance comes from the clash between lazily evaluated combinations and proper tail recursion over the combinations.
  - The unpredictable abuse of *thunks* to memoize the lazily evaluated expressions also makes troubles on the utilization of the machine resources (e.g. registers and the cache memory).
- Purely functional languages like Haskell may declare the referential transparency is a good thing<sup>TM</sup>. However, this is faulty in certain contexts.

  - There are semantic gaps over [the terminology itself](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/papers/SondergaardSestoft1990.pdf). The purity is not the only aspect for the referential transparency; moreover, there are other kinds of such property not readily provided by the evaluation strategy.
  - In general, referential transparency should not be a goal about programming. Instead, it is an optional manner to implement the composable components of programs. Composability is essentially about the expected invariance on the interface of the components. There are many ways to keep the composability without the aid of any kinds of referential transparency. Whether the guarantee should be enforced by the language rules? It depends. At least, it should not depend totally on the language designers' point.
- The lack of impure evaluations requires more syntax noises to encode many constructs simply expressible by mutable state cells in the traditional impure languages. The workarounds of the practical problems do make the solution more difficult and hard to reason by humans.

  - For example, I/O operations are side-effectful, thus not *directly* expressible in Haskell expressions under the usual non-strict evaluation rules, otherwise the order of effects will be non-deterministic.
  - To overcoming the shortcoming, some *indirect* conventional constructs like [the `IO` monad to simulate the traditional imperative style are proposed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1993/01/imperative.pdf). Such monadic constructs are in essential "indirect" in the sense similar to the [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), which is considerably low-level and difficult to read. Even though monads can be "powerful" than continuations in expresiveness, it does not naturally powerful than more high-level alternatives (like algebraic effect systems) when the lazy evaluation strategy is not enforced by default.
  - Besides the intuition problem above, the necessity of using monadic constructs are often difficult to prove formally (if ever possible). As the result, they are *very* easily abused (just like the design patterns for "OOP" languages derived from Simula). The related syntax sugar, notably, [the famous `do`-notation, is abused](https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful) for a few decades before well-known by the Haskell community.
- Simulating strict language constructs in languages like Haskell usually needs monadic constructs, while simulating non-strict constructs in strict languages are considerably simpler and easier to implement efficiently. For instance, there is [SRFI-45](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-45/srfi-45.html).
- The lazy evaluation strategy does not deal with many other non-strict constructs well.

  - For example, [`seq` has to be a compiler magic in GHC](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/seq-magic). This is not easily expressible by other Haskell constructs without massive changes in the core Haskell language rules.
  - Although traditional strict languages also do not allow user programs to simulate the enforcement of the order easily so such sequential constructs are therefore primitive (examples: C-like `;` is primitive; the derivation of Scheme's `begin` is relying on the primitive `lambda` which in turn implying an implicit evaluation order on expressions), it can be implementable reusing the applicative order rules without additional ad-hoc primitives, like [the derivation of the`$sequence` operator in the Kernel language](https://ftp.cs.wpi.edu/pub/techreports/pdf/05-07.pdf).

## Concerns about specific questions

1. Lazy evaluation is not a must for the "functional paradigm", though as mentioned above, purely functional languages are likely have the lazy evaluation strategy by default. The common properties are the usability of first-class functions. Impure languages like Lisp and ML family are considered "functional", which use eager evaluation by default. Also note the popularity of "functional paradigm" came after the introducing of [function-level programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function-level_programming). The latter is quite different, but still somewhat similar to "functional programming" on the treatment of first-classness.
2. As mentioned above, the way to simulate laziness in eager languages are well-known. Additionally, for pure programs, there may be no non-trivially semantic difference between call-by-need and normal order reduction. To figure out something really only work in a lazy world is actually not easy. (Do you want to implement the language?) Just go ahead.

## Conclusion

Be careful to the problem domain. Lazy evaluation may work well for specific scenarios. However, making it by default is likely to be a bad idea in general, because users (whoever to use the language to program, or to derive a new dialect based on the current language) will likely have few chances to ignore all of the problems it will cause.

Answer (score -2):

Well, try to think of something that would work if lazily evaluated, that wouldn't if eagerly evaluated. The most common category of these would be lazy logical operator evaluation used to hide a "side effect". I'll use C#-ish language to explain, but functional languages would have similar analogs.

Take the simple C# lambda:

```
(a,b) => a==0 || ++b < 20
```

In a lazy-evaluated language, if a==0, the expression ++b < 20 is not evaluated (because the entire expression evaluates to true either way), which means that b is not incremented. In both imperative and functional languages, this behavior (and similar behavior of the AND operator) can be used to "hide" logic containing side effects that should not be executed:

```
(a,b) => a==0 && save(b)
```

"a" in this case may be the number of validation errors. If there were validation errors, the first half fails and the second half is not evaluated. If there were no validation errors, the second half is evaluated (which would include the side effect of trying to save b) and the result (apparently true or false) is returned to be evaluated. If either side evaluates to false, the lambda returns false indicating that b was not successfully saved. If this were evaluated "eagerly", we would try to save regardless of the value of "a", which would probably be bad if a nonzero "a" indicated that we shouldn't.

Side effects in functional languages are generally considered a no-no. However, there are few non-trivial programs that do not require at least one side effect; there's generally no other way to make a functional algorithm integrate with non-functional code, or with peripherals like a data store, display, network channel, etc.

Comment: -1: short-circuited operators != lazy evaluation. In C#, && and || are short-circuited and eagerly evaluated, meaning the program executes the value at the point of declaration. In Haskell land, the equivalent expression would not be evaluated until you interrogate its value.

Comment: @Juliet: Short-circuiting is often used as an example of a special case obviated by laziness, but I find it unsatisfying for pretty much that reason. A slightly better example in C# might be the two branches in a conditional operator, where only evaluating one is more likely to be important. Still kinda flimsy though, with everything else being so eager.

Comment: @camccann: short-circuiting is not a special case of laziness, the two concepts are orthogonal to one another. In a lazy language, `let x = a == 0 && save(b)` is equivalent to `Lazy<bool> x = Lazy.Create(() => a.Value == 0 && save(b)` -- in other words, x, a, and b are just code thunks of the type `Lazy<bool>`, they have no value until you ask for it (afterward the value is cached). If you never interrogate the value of x, then the expression `a == 0` code won't execute at all. Haskell transparently assigns every value the type `Lazy<whatever>`, this is what people mean by a laziness.

Comment: @Juliet: Right, I know--I meant that short-circuiting is usually a special case with different semantics added on top of an eager language's normal evaluation strategy, whereas with laziness it's superfluous, not that it's a special case of laziness itself. For instance, `(&&)` in Haskell is non-strict in its second argument, imitating the expected "short-circuit" behavior, but it'd be just as easy to make it non-strict in the first, or strict in both.

Comment: @Juliet: The concepts are not orthogonal, i.e. independent. In a lazy language, built-in special short-circuting || is not needed.

Comment: Short-circuited operations does not imply lazy evaluation, but non-strict evaluation. They are not eagerly evaluated, either. Only specific operand in a subexpression are evaluated using the usual eager rules. OTOH, all operands of a lazy operator are evaluated by need.